# How can I iterate through a tree structure and return only certain values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

The title kind of says it all, I'm currently struggling with this problem, in which I have an array that is something like this:

**What I have**

```
[
  {
    "label": "X-1",
    "checked": false,
    "value": 1,
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "X-1-1",
        "checked": false,
        "value": 11,
        "isOperation": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "label": "X-1-2",
        "checked": false,
        "value": 12,
        "isOperation": true,
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "label": "X-1-3",
        "checked": false,
        "value": 13,
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "X-1-3-1",
            "checked": false,
            "value": 131,
            "isOperation": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "label": "X-1-3-2",
            "checked": true,
            "value": 132,
            "isOperation": true,
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "label": "X-1-3-3",
            "checked": false,
            "value": 1313,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "label": "X-2",
    "checked": true,
    "value": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "X-2-1",
        "checked": true,
        "value": 21,
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I have to return **only** the the values with `checked: true`, with this structure:

**What I have to return**

```
[
  {
    "TransactionId": 1312,
    "Description": "X-1-3-2",
    "TransactionChild": []
  },
  {
    "TransactionId": 2,
    "Description": "X-2",
    "TransactionChild": [
      {
        "TransactionId": "21",
        "Description": "X-2-1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**as requested, what I've got so far**

```
const convertTreeDataToTransactionSelected = (node: TreeNodeProps[]): TreeItem[] => {
    let treeData: TreeItem[] = [];
    if (node.length > 1) {
      treeData = node.map(el => {
        return {
          Description: el.label,
          TransactionId: Number(el.value),
          TransactionChild: el.children ? convertTreeDataToTransactionSelected(el.children) : [],
        };
      });
    }
    return treeData;
};
```

How can I do such thing?(yes I know that the best way is using recursion but I failed to get the desired return `value`)

Keep in mind that if all `children` are checked the parent is checked as well (the same goes, if the `parent` is checked it means that all `children` are checked too)

Comment: Consider using a recursive function?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i've tried but couldn't get te return value that its required

Comment: Can you show the recursive function that you have tried so far?

Comment: @AaronMorefield added the code to the question

Comment: Please read [ask] (and the sites linked therein) for tips on asking questions that are less likely to be downvoted.

Comment: where is `1312` coming from and why?

Comment: Note that your function returns an empty array if there is only one node in the array. Not sure why that is. There's also no check for whether the `checked` property is true or false.

Comment: @NinaScholz, my bad, should have explained it better. But the `TransactionId` is relative to the `value` of the selected node

Comment: @iReallyNeedYourHelp, yes, but that is not the question. the question is, why is this node in the result set?

Comment: @NinaScholz again sorry, I've edited the question. I missed `checked:true` in that node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two function for getting nested nodes and another to get root or starting node which match the wanted constraint.

For changing the properties, you could add a wrapper, but this is not important than to get the overall functionality.

```js
const
    getNestedNodes = (children, cb) => q => {
        if (cb(q)) {
            return [{ ...q, children: q.children.flatMap(getNestedNodes(children, cb)) }]
        } else {
            children.push(...getNodes(q.children, cb));
            return [];
        }
    },
    getNodes = (data, cb) => data.flatMap(o => {
        if (cb(o)) {
            const children = [];
            return [
                { ...o, children: o.children.flatMap(getNestedNodes(children, cb)) },
                ...children
            ];
        } else {
            return getNodes(o.children, cb);
        }
    }),
    data = [{ label: "X-1", checked: false, value: 1, children: [{ label: "X-1-1", checked: false, value: 11, isOperation: true, children: [] }, { label: "X-1-2", checked: false, value: 12, isOperation: true, children: [] }, { label: "X-1-3", checked: false, value: 13, children: [{ label: "X-1-3-1", checked: false, value: 131, isOperation: true, children: [] }, { label: "X-1-3-2", checked: true, value: 132, isOperation: true, children: [] }, { label: "X-1-3-3", checked: false, value: 1313, children: [{ label: "X-1-3-3-1", checked: true, value: 1331, children: [] }] }] }] }, { label: "X-2", checked: true, value: 2, children: [{ label: "X-2-1", checked: true, value: 21, children: [{ label: "X-2-1-1", checked: false, value: 211, children: [{ label: "X-2-1-1-1", checked: true, value: 2111, children: [] }] }] }] }],
    result = getNodes(data, ({ checked }) => checked);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've accepted the answer from Nina Scholz, I assume that that output format is what you want, namely all the elements of the tree that match, returned as a flat array.

But if you're interested, here is an alternative form, which keeps the tree structure intact, returning all matching nodes along with all of their ancestors.

```js
const deepFilter = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (({children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = deepFilter (pred) (children)) =>
    pred (rest) || kids.length
      ? [{...rest, ...(kids.length ? {children: kids} : {})}]
      : []
  )

const keepChecked = deepFilter (x => x .checked)

const input = [{label: "X-1", checked: false, value: 1, children: [{label: "X-1-1", checked: false, value: 11, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-2", checked: false, value: 12, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3", checked: false, value: 13, children: [{label: "X-1-3-1", checked: false, value: 131, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3-2", checked: true, value: 132, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3-3", checked: false, value: 1313, children: []}]}]}, {label: "X-2", checked: true, value: 2, children: [{label: "X-2-1", checked: true, value: 21, children: []}]}]

console .log (keepChecked (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with a generic tree-filtering function that has this behavior based on an arbitrary predicate, and then write our main function as a simple call passing a predicate which tests if the value is `checked`.

---

Also unclear was if you actually had to do a transformation of the sample input structure into your target output, or if that sample was a simplification for the question which didn't get applied to the output.

If you actually need to do that transformation (that is from `value`, `label`, and `children` to `TransactionId`, `Description`, and `TransactionChild`), we could use a dedicated `filterMap` function, which does the filtering and mapping in one go

```js
const deepFilterMap = (pred, transform) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (({children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = deepFilterMap (pred, transform) (children)) =>
    pred (rest) || kids.length
      ? [transform (rest, kids)]
      : []
  )

const convert = deepFilterMap (
  x => x .checked,
  ({label, value}, children) => ({
    TransactionId: value,
    Description: label,
    ... (children .length ? {TransactionChild: children} : {})
  })
)

const input = [{label: "X-1", checked: false, value: 1, children: [{label: "X-1-1", checked: false, value: 11, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-2", checked: false, value: 12, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3", checked: false, value: 13, children: [{label: "X-1-3-1", checked: false, value: 131, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3-2", checked: true, value: 132, isOperation: true, children: []}, {label: "X-1-3-3", checked: false, value: 1313, children: []}]}]}, {label: "X-2", checked: true, value: 2, children: [{label: "X-2-1", checked: true, value: 21, children: []}]}]

console .log (convert (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Or of course we could write a `deepMap` function which we could combine with `deepFilter` as necessary.  Something like this might do:

```js
const deepMap = (transform) => (xs) =>
  xs .map (({children = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = deepMap (transform) (children)) => transform ({
    ... rest, 
    ... (kids.length ? {children: kids} : {})
  }))
```